# get 404 error for local web server

Tags: server, apache2, localhost

I installed Apache also make sub directory under www
like /www/azolfagharj
make azolfagharj.conf
like this

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
DocumentRoot /var/www/azolfagharj
ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
```

but when trying to open "http://localhost/azolfagharj"
get 404 error
for all www sub directory

Comment: You've set your `DocumentRoot` to be `/var/www/azolfagharj`, which means that `/var/www/azolfagharj` is going to be the starting point for Apache when you visit http://localhost.

Comment: for see "http://localhost/azolfagharj"  what should I do؟

Comment: i set it just for virtual host for /var/www/azolfagharj  not all of Apache  , default page is still var/www/html